# Abilities of SuperCSV

Tags: supercsv

I'm looking at using SuperCSV to check the contents of some files that I receive. The format of the file is such that it has a header record followed by the data records followed by a CRC32 checksum value.

e.g.

```
ABC|2|20130115150327|
1|1234567890123456|1234|20130109204710|21130109204710|
2|6543210987654321|1234|20130110043658|21130110043658|
1A345C7D
```

I have a few questions about the capabilities of SuperCSV in this situation.

- Does it allow you to validate different lines against different
  definitions i.e. one for the header record and one for the data
  records?
- Does it allow you to validate that the delimiter (pipe '|'
  in this case) must be appended to the end of the line?
- Is there, or has anybody written, a CellProcessor that validates hexadecimal values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - Does it allow you to validate different lines against different
>     definitions i.e. one for the header record and one for the data
>     records?

Yes. Typically, you'd read the header with `getHeader()`, which doesn't use CellProcessors, but there's nothing stopping you from just reading the header as a normal line with `read()` using CellProcessors. Each call to `read()` lets you pass in the CellProcessors, so you can process/validate the header, data rows and checksum differently using 3 different CellProcessor arrays.

> - Does it allow you to validate that the delimiter (pipe '|' in this
>     case) must be appended to the end of the line?

As you're using `|` as the delimiter, then the last column will be treated as an empty column (`null`). This means that your CellProcessor array for reading the header will have to have 4 elements (or 6 for the data rows), otherwise you will get an exception saying that the number of columns doesn't match the number of cell processors. By putting an `new Equals(null)` processor at the end, you can essentially validate that the line ends with a `|`.

> - Is there, or has anybody written, a CellProcessor that validates
>     hexadecimal values?

You can use the existing cell processor `new StrRegex("[0-9A-F]+")` to validate using a regular expression. You can even register a human-readable message for the validation error  (e.g. "not a valid hex value") using [StrRegex.registerMessage()](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/cellprocessor/constraint/StrRegEx.html#method_summary).

If you want to parse the hex as a number (probably not, but just in case), then there's no existing `ParseHex` CellProcessor in Super CSV. If you write one and submit a patch, I'll include it in the upcoming release! Depending on how big the number is, maybe it's best to update [ParseLong](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/cellprocessor/ParseLong.html) to have another constructor that accepts a radix (16 in this case)?

I'd recommend keeping things simple and using [CsvListReader](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/io/CsvListReader.html) (you could use the other readers, but you'll need to define a nameMapping array to provide column names for the header, data and checksum rows) as follows:

1. Read the first line (I'm assuming the second column is the number of following data rows?) using the 'header' CellProcessor array.
2. Read the data rows *n* times (where *n* is given by the 2nd header column) using the 'data' CellProcessor array.
3. Read the checksum using the 'checksum' CellProcessor array (probably just a single `ParseChecksum()`).