# Using SuperCSV to Change Header Values

Tags: java, supercsv

In line with this post about [abilities of SuperCSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328668/abilities-of-supercsv), can SuperCSV handle changing the values of the headers(***column names only***) read from the database?

For example, the following code snippet details the Current State and the Expected State.

### Current State

**INPUT**:

```
final String[] header = new String[] { "firstName", "lastName", "birthDate"};

// write the header
beanWriter.writeHeader(header);

// write the beans
for( final CustomerBean customer : customers ) {
   beanWriter.write(customer, header, processors);
}
```

**OUTPUT**: file with column names:

```
firstName, lastName, birthDate
Bob      , Doe     , 02/12/2013
```

### Expected State

**INPUT**:

```
final String[] header = new String[] { "firstName", "lastName", "birthDate"};

// write the header
beanWriter.writeHeader(header);

// write the beans
for( final CustomerBean customer : customers ) {
   beanWriter.write(customer, header, processors);
}

// modify the headers
 ??????
```

**OUTPUT**: file with *modified* column names:

```
First Name, Last Name, Birthday
Bob      , Doe     , 02/12/2013
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but you can put whatever you like in the header - it doesn't have to be identical to the mapping array passed to `beanWriter.write()`

For example, the following will give the output you desire:

```
final String[] header = new String[] { "First Name", "Last Name", "Birthday"};
final String[] fieldMapping = new String[] { "firstName", "lastName", "birthDate"};

// write the header
beanWriter.writeHeader(header);

// write the beans
for( final CustomerBean customer : customers ) {
   beanWriter.write(customer, fieldMapping , processors);
}
```